# Как использовать 'сигнатуру проблемы' при зависании

Tags: delphi, windows

Я пишу программу, компилирую, запускаю, она зависает и в подробностях проблемы есть 'Сигнатуры проблемы'. А теперь вопрос, что значит 'Доп. сигнатура зависания' как ее можно использовать для решения проблемы?[image: exe не отвечает][image: exe не отвечает 2]

Comment: А можно скриншот, ато ничего не ясно. В крайнем случае запустите програму под отладкой.

Comment: О чем речь? Какие еще "подробности проблемы" и "сигнатуры проблемы"?

Comment: лучше исходники программы приложить. Там будет больше инфорации. А это окно - это винда сама поняла, что приложение тупит и пытается помочь. Но откуда в интернетах знать о Вашей программе:)?

Answer (score 1):

Эти сведения Вам не помогут.
Для отлова "почему" и "где" приложение зависло, используйте дополнительные инструменты, такие как [EurekaLog](https://www.eurekalog.com/) или [MadExcept](http://madshi.net/) (последняя бесплатна для некоммерческого использования). Они отобразят полный стек вызовов Вашего кода, который привел к зависанию основного потока.

Примечание: если Вы используете RAD 10 Seattle без Update1 и компилируете под 64бит, то эти (да и любые другие) инструменты могут оказаться бессильны, т.к. [Seattle’s Win64 compiler’s generated code isn’t deterministic anymore](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2015/10/ide-fix-pack-how-do-i-know-i-didnt-break-the-compiler/)